# how to search with populated field key value name in node js and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, backend

In this collection i want to find a record which have a movieData field which can be populated and have key value pairs ( Objects ) and i want a particular record with a given query in node js

```
collection.find({userData:userData ,movieData: { Name: "pirate fairy" } })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to search with populated field key value name in Node.js and MongoDB:

```
collection.find({userData:userData ,"movieData.Name": "pirate fairy"})
```